# Aura Component: Get Id of Lookup field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I am developing aura component in Salesforce (new in this) and I have found a problem with the calls of Lookup fields.

I have one aura component with table where you can see info about differents QuoteLineItems. This object (QuoteLineItem) has two Lookup fields to FinancialProject_PEP__c. I want two urls buttons that redirects the user to this sObject detail page. The component is something like this:

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="QLIController">
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:handler name="RemoveRow" event="c:removeRow" action="{!c.removeRow}" />
    
    <aura:attribute name="row" type="QuoteLineItem"/> 

    <td data-label="Detail">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Detail">
                <a href="{!'https://MYORG--sqa.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/QuoteLineItem/' + v.row.Id + '/view'}" target="_self">{!$Label.c.Details}</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    
    <tr>
        
        <td data-label="Billing PEP">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Billing PEP">
                <a href="{!'https://MYORG--sqa.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/FinancialProject_PEP__c/' + v.row.BillingPEP__c + '/view'}" target="_self">{!$Label.c.BillingPEP}</a>  
            </div>
        </td>
        
        <td data-label="Expense PEP">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Expense PEP">
                <a href="{!'https://MYORG--sqa.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/FinancialProject_PEP__c/' + v.row.ExpensePEP__c + '/view'}" target="_self">{!$Label.c.ExpensePEP}</a>            
            </div>
        </td>
...
...
```

On detail column, I was able to call the url with **v.row.Id** and Salesforce redirects me to the detail page of the QuoteLineItem. But when I call the BillingPEP__c or ExpensePEP__c url, Salesforce show this error:

**Page doesn't exist, Enter a valid URL and try again**

Generating this url:

https://MYORG--sqa.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/FinancialProject_PEP__c//view

As you can see, the Id in URL is empty, but I have checked that the field in these record is not empty. I have tried different solutions like change the target, quit "sandbox" in URL, try different records, etc... but I don´t find how to call correctly the id of the lookup object.

Thank you all.

Comment: Are you sure your code is retrieving values for both the fields i.e. BillingPEP__c and ExpensePEP__c in the component? I think you should make sure by using some debug in javascript controller to make sure those values are being retrieved in the client-side controller.

Comment: Hi @jagmohan, first of all, thanks for your comment. I have used debug in javascript retrieving "v.row.Id" (the result of this is the id xxxxxxxx) and "v.row.BillingPEP__c" (result in console is undefined). This has no sense because other fields (like Description__c) are retrieving via "v.row.Description__c" without problems.

Comment: As you mentioned, v.row.BillingPEP__c is undefined, that's why those links aren't redirecting correctly. Once those values are retrieved, the links should work correctly.